# Prove $f$ is Lipschitz

Tags: calculus

Given $f:(0,1)^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $|f_x'|,f_y'|<M$
Try to prove:
For every $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1)\in(0,1)^2$ happen :
$|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\sqrt{2}Md((x_1,y_1)(x_0,y_0))$
where d() is the euclidean norm

Comment: $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|\leq|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_1,y_2)|+|f(x_1,y_2)-f(x_2,y_2)|=|f_y(x_1,y_3)||y_1-y_2|+|f_x(x_3,y_2)||x_1-x_2|\leq M(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)\leq \sqrt{2}Md((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$, where the first inequality was obtained by adding and subtracting $f(x_1,y_2)$ and the triangle inequality, the equation that follows is using the mean value theorem in the corresponding coordinate (the $x_3$ is some value between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $y_3$ between $y_1,y_2$), the next inequality is from the bounds given, and the last is Cauchy's inequality.

Comment: @OscarRascal can you explain just the last inequality please

Comment: The last one is Cauchy's inequality $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|=1\cdot|x_1-x_2|+1\cdot|y_1-y_2|\leq (1^2+1^2)^{1/2}(|x_1-x_2|^2+|y_1-y_2|^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: @OscarRascal cool thanks!

Comment: @OscarRascal - please answer questions in Answer posts, rather than in comments. Not only do you receive reputation from these answers, it allows others to see that the question has been answered. Without an answer showing, those with similar questions do not know that this thread has an answer. And those looking to answer questions will not know that question is answered.